# Relate email to record from custom lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am currently working on a Lightning Component to be used in Lightning for Gmail and outlook.

There are a bunch of standard components available for use in Lightning for Gmail. One of which is the Cases component. This component has an option of relating the email to the record.

[image]

I am trying to add this (Relate email to record) functionality in a custom lightning component.

Is there a way i can plugin this functionality into a custom lightning component or should it have built from scratch for the custom components?

Comment: As far as I know - you have to build it yourself, there is no standard way to add this to your custom component